# How to enable all control after background worker finishes WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a function that enables all controls but I want to call this in RunWorkerCompleted function.  How to properly use the Invoke method?

```
private void enableSingleControl(Control con)
{
    con.Enabled = true;
}

// function to enable all control on winform
private void enableControls2()
{
    foreach (Control child in this.Controls)
    {
        if (child.InvokeRequired)
        {
            child.Invoke(new Action<void>(enableSingleControl), child);
        }
        else 
        {
            child.Enabled = true;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: If you run this code in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler, what's the point in Invoking anything? The event is raised in the UI Thread.

Comment: because runworkercomplete is not on UI thread im assuming so I need to invoke.

Comment: Since you have `this.Controls` there, this code is clearly run inside `this` to have access to the collection. Hence, the BackgroundWorker is declared in the UI Thread and, as a consequence, the event is raised in the UI Thread. That's the whole point of `ReportProgress` and `RunWorkerCompleted`: run code in the Thread that created the BackgrounWorker. The `DoWork` event is instead raised in a ThreadPool Thread. That's the whole point of the `DoWork` event: run code in a thread context other than the Thread that created the BGW.

Comment: good to know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, and also doesn't flood the message queue.  Only need to marshal over to the GUI thread once.

```
private void EnableAllControls()
{
    //Are we on the UI thread?
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        //If not, marshal over.  This is blocking.
        Invoke(new Action(() => EnableAllControls()));
        return;
    }
    //We're on the UI thread
    foreach (Control child in Controls)
    {
        child.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

**Important note:**

Controls can have children of their own which the above does not handle.  Basically `child` could have children, and this nesting can continue.

Comment: Nice looks like I was close.